# What is the difference between these two combinations?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, combinations

Excerpt from *"Probability Theory: A Concise Course"*, Y.A. Rozanov (Chapter 2).

> A batch of 100 manufactured items contains 5 defective items. Fifty
>   items are chosen at random and then inspected. Suppose the whole batch
>   is accepted if no more than one of the 50 inspected items is
>   defective. What is the probability of accepting the whole batch?

**(A) My solution:**

N: The number of combinations of 100 items taken 50 at a time is: ${100\choose50}$

N(A): The number of ways we can select 50 items out of 95 (non-defective) + 1 (one defective allowed) items or 96 items: ${96\choose50}$

The probability is then: $P(A) = \frac{96\choose50}{100\choose50}$

**(B) Verified solution:**

N: The number of combinations of 100 items taken 50 at a time is: ${100\choose50}$

N(A): The number of ways we can select 50 items out of 95 non-defective ones in addition to the number of ways we can select 49 items out of 95 non-defective ones and 1 out of 5 defective items: ${95\choose50} + {95\choose49}{5\choose1}$

The probability is then: $P(A) = \frac{{95\choose50} + {95\choose49}{5\choose1}}{100\choose50}$

**My question:**
I understand the logic of the verified solution B but I can't get how it is different from A. With my first solution am I not computing the number of ways of arranging 50 items out of 96 items (95 good and 1 defective)?

Can you please also give me in plain english what the solution A does?

Thank you all

Comment: I would look at the explicit binomial coefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because at no point in the process are you selecting 50 items from 96 options. You don't add to the top number in binomial coefficients like that.

Let $A$ be the event that none of the 50 are defected and let $B$ be the event exactly 1 is defective. We want the probability of the event $A \ \cup B $ (A or B). That is the probability that either none of the 50 are defective or exactly 1 is defective. Both are acceptable.

Because they are mutually exclusive, $P(A \ \cup B \,) = P(A) + P(B)$

The total number of ways of picking 50 items from 100 is $\binom{100}{50}$

There are 95 non-defective items.

$P(A)$:

Here you need to choose 50 items from the 95 non-defective ones.

There are $\binom{95}{50}$ ways to do this, so

$$P(A) = \frac{\binom{95}{50}}{\binom{100}{50}}$$

$P(B)$

Here you use the rule of product. You can break down the task of choosing 50 items, 1 of which is defective, into choosing 49 non-defective items (out of 95) and choosing 1 defective item (out of 5).

There are $\binom{95}{49}$ ways of doing the first part and $\binom{5}{1}$ ways of doing the second.

Thus P(B) = $$\frac{\binom{95}{49}\binom{5}{1}}{\binom{100}{50}}$$

Altogether we have

$$P(A \ \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) = \frac{\binom{95}{50}}{\binom{100}{50}} + \frac{\binom{95}{49}\binom{5}{1}}{\binom{100}{50}} = \frac{\binom{95}{50} + \binom{95}{49}\binom{5}{1}}{\binom{100}{50}}$$